# How to reverse the SSIS Data Flow?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

Currently I have on SSIS package which reads the fixed length string and dump in to SQL-Server Tables.
Current Flow:
[Flat File Read Task] --> [Multicast] --> [Insert Multiple Tables].
Desired Flow:

[Flat File Read Task] <-- [Multicast] <-- [Insert Multiple Tables].

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, just use a Flat File Destination and a OLEDB Destination instead. SSIS can import/export with many different sources, it doesn't *have* to use SQL Server as the final target.

Comment: OLEDB Source* (whoops).